# Im getting this error everytime i try to run this project on replit.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Stardew-Processing/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import section
  File "/home/runner/Stardew-Processing/section.py", line 1, in <module>
    import display
  File "/home/runner/Stardew-Processing/display.py", line 4, in <module>
    settings = json.load(f)
  File "/nix/store/8w6mm5q1n7i7cs1933im5vkbgvjlglfn-python3-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/nix/store/8w6mm5q1n7i7cs1933im5vkbgvjlglfn-python3-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/nix/store/8w6mm5q1n7i7cs1933im5vkbgvjlglfn-python3-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/nix/store/8w6mm5q1n7i7cs1933im5vkbgvjlglfn-python3-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 2 (char 22)
```

I am unsure on how to reslove it if i need to link the project I can I am a newer programmer and I am doing this project as practice so any tips are greatly appreciated

`https://replit.com/@Budvy/Stardew-Processing`

I was expecting it to run and it did not

Comment: You need to include a [mcve]

Comment: Your `settings.json` is not valid, check it with a linter. Missing comma at end of line 2.